# Add numbering to duplicate array items

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a script to increment values that are repeated in an array. For example, an array containing these 5 values:

```
Test
Testing
Test
Testing Again
Test
```

Should become:

```
Test
Testing
Test 1
Testing Again
Test 2
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $custom_fields = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'fields', false);
    $custom_field_occurences = [];

    foreach ($custom_fields as $key => $value) {

        if (!in_array($value, array_keys($custom_field_occurences))) {
            // First instance, doesn't need to be incremented,
            $custom_field_occurences[$value] = 0;
        } else {
            // Already exists, increment it by the number of occurences.
            $custom_field_occurences[$value]++;
            $incremented_value = $value . ' ' . $custom_field_occurences[$value];
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fields', $incremented_value, $value );
        }

    }
```

The problem I'm currently having is that the function turns the array into this:

```
Test 1
Testing
Test 1
Testing Again
Test 1
```

I have also tried this variation:

```
        foreach ($cleaned_custom_fields as $key => $value) {

            if (!in_array($value, array_keys($custom_field_occurences))) {
                // First instance, doesn't need to be incremented,
                $custom_field_occurences[$value] = 0;
            } else {
                // Already exists, increment it by the number of occurences.
                $custom_field_occurences[$value]++;
            }

            $incremented_value = $value . ' ' . $custom_field_occurences[$value];
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-logbook-text-fields', $incremented_value, $value );

        }
```

But that results in

```
Test 0
Testing 0
Test 0
Testing Again 0
Test 0
```

How can I ensure the function incrementally numbers the repeating values, making them unique?

Comment: This absolutely did not need a new question! Please un-delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775050/, and continue the discussion in there.

Comment: (I already responded to your current minor problem in the comments under the previous version of your question, right before you decided to delete it.)

Comment: @CBroe the question was closed because apparently it wasn't focused enough (not sure why that was the case)

Comment: Ah, okay, I did not see it got closed in the meantime. (Why? Because “show me the best way to do X”, is not an appropriate way to ask here.) So, my comment from there again then:

Comment: @CBroe if I make the changes you suggest, every value (including unqiue values) ends up with a 0 on the end.

Comment: You stuffed too much into the `else` branch now. Only the incrementing of that counter value belongs in there, creating the proper value and making the update, belongs outside of the if/else, because you want to do that in any case.

Comment: _“if I make the changes you suggest”_ - show what exactly you did then, otherwise we can not tell if you did not perhaps make just the next mistake right away.

Comment: @CBroe perhaps I've misunderstood what you meant- I've added what I think you meant to my question above.

Comment: @CBroe and for what it's worth, I don't always need to update the value. I only need to update it if it isn't unique, which is why I had the update_post_meta in the else branch.

Comment: Doesn’t explain why multiple of the same values would get the same suffix. Can you please show what exactly your input data is here, `var_dump($custom_fields);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution ended up being this:

```
        $cleaned_custom_fields = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'fields', false);
        $incremented_fields = [];
        $field_occurences = [];

        foreach ($cleaned_custom_fields as $key => $value) {

            if (!in_array($value, array_keys($incremented_fields))) {
                // First instance, doesn't need to be incremented. Just push it 
                array_push($incremented_fields, $value);
                $field_occurences[$value] = 0;
            } else {
                // Already exists, increment it by the number of occurences.
                $field_occurences[$value]++;
                $incremented_value = $value . ' ' . $field_occurences[$value];
                array_push($incremented_fields, $incremented_value);
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fields', $incremented_value, $value );
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this will work

```
<?php  
$arrayName = array('Test','Testing','Test','Testing again','Test','Testing');

for($i=0;$i<count($arrayName);$i++){
    $c=1;
    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($arrayName);$j++){
        if($arrayName[$i]==$arrayName[$j]){
            $arrayName[$j].=$c;
            $c++;
        }
    }
}
for($i=0;$i<count($arrayName);$i++){
    echo $arrayName[$i].'<br>';
}
?>
```